# OpenGL slow cubes/voxels rendering (3M triangles at 40 fps). Seems like sending a whole scene to GPU every frame

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering, voxel

I've implemented basic textured cubes rendering engine (Minecraft style) in C++ and OpenGL. A static scene containing 3 million triangles with no lighting renders at 38 fps, 25ms frame time. It seems very slow. Also running on integrated Intel GPU is faster than dedicated Nvidia, which is a bad sign. This is my first project in graphics programming and OpenGL.

**Description**

Cubes are joined into chunk VAOs and those are rendered. Chunk size is 32x32x32, only visible cube faces are added to vertices/elements buffers. Empty chunks skip rendering entirely. Back face culling and texture atlas are used, other optimizations are not (and I don't want to, IMHO it should work faster even without those). Shaders are plain simple. World size is 11x11x11 chunks.

**Investigation**

- Reducing scene size in cubes proportionally changes frame time - 2x faster for 2x less cubes
- Profiling with Intel VTune shows ~95% CPU utilization in glfwSwapBuffers - rendering is a bottleneck
- Window size and disabling textures do not affect frame time - fragment shader is not a bottleneck
- Changing chunk size (while keeping same world size in cubes) from 32x32x32 to 16x16x16 (8x more VAOs, from 808 to 4393) does not affect frame time
- Profiling with Nvidia Nsight Frame profiler shows 25ms of GPU in glDrawElements - looks like a problem
- Nvidia Nsight GPU trace profiler is not available to me as it requires Turing+ GPU
- (!) Running on an integrated Intel HD Graphics 630 is 4 fps faster than Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 - might be a memory bottleneck as an integrated card uses PC memory which might be faster for buffer transfers.
- Scene contains 6,393,968 vertices and 3,196,984 triangles, 5 floats per vertex (pos + uv), 3 ints per triangle = 166 MB per scene. Not that much, unless I send it every frame. But I don't do that.
- Search shows Nvidia GTX 660 send bandwidth to be 7 GB/s, fine for an estimate, it will take me 23 ms to transfer the scene. Oops.

But I don't do this in code, what is going on and how to fix it? Is it possible that OpenGL decided to store buffers in local memory? Maybe I missed something in the docs? Maybe the problem is not with the bandwidth at all?

**Materials**

Loading chunk mesh (once per chunk, at init):

```
    materialShader.use();

    glGenBuffers(1, &verticesId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (GLsizeiptr) meshData.verticesSize, meshData.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    materialShader.attrib("aPos", 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uvId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (GLsizeiptr) meshData.uvsSize, meshData.uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    materialShader.attrib("aTexCoord", 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    glGenBuffers(1, &elementsId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementsId);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (GLsizeiptr) meshData.elementsSize, meshData.elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementsId);
```

* materialShader.attrib = glVertexAttribPointer; glEnableVertexAttribArray

Rendering chunk mesh (each chunk, each frame), pseudocode in correct order, actual code is abstracted:

```
    glUseProgram // use shader, skipped if used last
    glBindVertexArray // use vao, skipped if used last
    glBindTexture // use texture atlas, skipped if used last 
    glUniformMatrix4fv // set transform matrix in shader
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLint) elementsSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr) // draw chunk mesh
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
    if (texColor.a < 0.01) {
        discard;
    }
    FragColor = texColor;
}
```

**What is also going on**

During init: generating terrain with OpenGL compute shaders and SSBO.

Each frame: render debug text on the screen, not very optimized but ~1000 fps on it's own.

Comment: Most GPUs these days are optimized for / expect a whole frame each draw. They do their own culling of invisible geometry etc.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can you elaborate? I do render the whole scene every frame.

Comment: Also, when benchmarking anything related to performance, be sure that you are testing an optimized build and not just a default "debug" build (which is usually going to be very slow).

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah, I know, but afaik it is related to CPU performance, not shaders. Shaders are built during runtime, and in my case CPU only waits for frames to render (glfwSwapBuffers is to wait for previous frame). OpenGL is already compiled, so it won't help.

Comment: I have to cast my vote as "Needs debugging details" -- there isn't much here we can do other than speculate. Yet to be helpful -- other things you can check: only ever bind one texture atlas. If the texture is big, the driver may be transferring it each time to/from system memory. Try putting all chunks into the same VAO. Try using smaller types for indices and vertex data.

Comment: @Squid233 thanks for the recommendation! I did this before but decided that since it only needed to be done once per vertex in shader and my meshes are big it is better to just compute transform once per vao on the CPU. Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: @YakovGalka thanks! I only switch to texture atlas once. Though I wanted to use more at some point, now I will be more cautious with it. I'll try changing VAO size and elements types